# VC++: std::(w)ifstream poor performance

Tags: c#, c++, windows, io, std

I have a rather large text file (about 5 000 000 lines, about 350 MB). It's a test file, so all lines look the same:

> 25.07.2014 1:00:22 | f2b5867b-51d2-4d06-b1a1-21bad529652c | Test message
>
> 25.07.2014 1:00:22 | fe4fea0c-2ef7-4f34-b78c-fa561c826171 | Test message
>
> 25.07.2014 1:00:22 | e6e11dc0-0ae8-40ac-9ab0-bd219636a5b2 | Test message

I've written two really simple applications in C# and VC++ that read lines one by one and count them:

C#:

```
private static void Run()
{
    const string file = @"C:\Foo\Bar.txt";

    var stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
    stopwatch.Start();
    var lineCount = EnumerateLines(file).Count();
    Console.WriteLine(lineCount);
    stopwatch.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine(stopwatch.Elapsed);
}

private static IEnumerable<string> EnumerateLines(string file)
{
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(file))
    {
        while(reader.EndOfStream == false)
        {
            yield return reader.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

C++:

```
StopWatch stopwatch;
stopwatch.Start();
std::wifstream stream;
stream.open("C:\\Foo\\Bar.txt", std::ios_base::in);
DWORD lineCount = 0;
std::wstring line;
while (std::getline(stream, line))
{
    lineCount++;
}

stopwatch.Stop();
std::cout << lineCount << std::endl;
std::cout << stopwatch.GetElapsedTime() << std::endl;
```

These programs do the same thing, but the performance is all over the place:

- C# - ~1.7 seconds
- C++ (with wifstream and wstring) - ~39 seconds
- C++ (with ifstream and string) - ~5.5 seconds

All applications were build using 'Release' configuration.

Could you please explain this to me? Why C# program performs much better? Why wifstream performs much worse than ifstream?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

I've also tried to use manual buffer size:

```
const auto lineSize = 1024; // .NET's StreamReader bufferSize is 1024 by default
wchar_t line[lineSize];
while (stream.getline(line, lineSize))
{
    lineCount++;
}
```

This way the performance is a little bit better (~37 seconds for wifstream, ~4.1 seconds for ifstream), but still wifstream is very slow.

Comment: Use `ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);` otherwise you're carrying C-compatibility stuff with you

Comment: @MarcoA. Thanks for the tip, but the performance remains the same

Comment: You could also try the `fgets()` heritage. It's probably going to be faster (not a wrapper).

Comment: You'll never get it close.  The standard C++ library suffers from having been specified without any regards to thread-safety.  Which forced library implementers to deal with the problem, there's heavy fine-grained locking in the code to keep it thread-safe.  So that for example one thread changing the locale doesn't screw up another one busy reading a file.  Locking is expensive, even if it doesn't get contested.  Not a problem in .NET, culture is a thread-local property.  It is in the OS as well, so not hard to implement, just not in the C++ spec.